# Why clause IF EXISTS is ignored by DROP TABLE?

Tags: apache-spark

After table `tt` creation the command works fine,

```
sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS h_db.tt")
```

but if I do again, the "IF EXISTS" is ignored, and Spark say a big message.

```
19/10/09 14:52:34 WARN DropTableCommand: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: `h_db`.`tt`;;
'UnresolvedRelation`h_db`.`tt`

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: `h_db`.`tt`;;
'UnresolvedRelation `h_db`.`tt`

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
....
```

I am using Spark 2.2.

Comment: It is not my software problem, and Spark say "WARN"... not "ERROR"... Perhaps a solution is to say "QUIET" before the command, and "NOT QUIET" after command: it is possible?

Comment: This was fixed in 2.3.0 - SPARK-22488 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22488. What version are you using?

Comment: Hi @shay__, thanks (!). Well, I need to wait my infrastructure team, we are using Spark 2.2.